# What is MS Graph API to fetch childrens for a folder in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

1. what is the graph API to fetch the content of a folder in Microsoft Sharepoint?
2. What is the graph API to fetch the content of a file ?
3. Here the api to fetch the root elements works.
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive

Answer (score 0):

> what is the graph API to fetch the content of a folder in Microsoft
>   Sharepoint?

No specific API for this, you can try this workaround:

1. Use the following endpoint to get the file/sub-folder list in the root folder(**if you know the folder name, you can jump to step 2 directly**).

   /drives/driveid/root:/{folder-name}:/children

Then check the item if have **folder** properties. We need to do this by ourselves(in-memory filter or such).

```
 "folder": {
                "childCount": 3
            }
```

2. Get file/sub-folder list in the folder.

   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/drive-id/root:/sub-folder-name:/
3. Do other logic on file based on your requirement by your self.

> What is the graph API to fetch the content of a file ?

```
Get /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

More infomation: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_get

Comment: Thanks for the reply, What is the purpose of the below rest api.  
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children
I tried this, but its not working.

Comment: It just list the item in the current folder level. Not all endpoint in the docs is  user-friendly, we need test one by one before use them. I have not dug why  /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children doesn't work, so I just provide worked solution on my side.